# Best strategy to discover a web service in a local network?

Tags: web-services, networking, compatibility

I am currently doing some research for a project. The setup is simple, I have a computer running a service in my home network and any device connected to that same network should be able to discover the service automatically and use it. I have no specific technology requirement whether it is on the server or client side. The client knows about the service definition.

Other than that I have no idea what strategy to use, what technology to look at or whether I should go for a SOAP or a HTTP based service. I think going HTTP with REST API is the best for targeting all devices but I am opened to any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to achieve this is to use UDP broadcast. Essentially:

1. The server listens for UDP packets on a certain port.
2. When a client wants to connect to the server, it sends a broadcast UDP packet to the certain port.
3. When the server sees a broadcast packet, it replies to that client with information about what the actual address/URL of the server is.

There are established standards that build upon this idea, for example [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS).

Comment: Thanks very much for that info. Sounds like a pretty good possibility.

Comment: Your clue lead me to chose UPnP which makes use of SSDP as a discovery protocol (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol). Of course that one is based on UDP broadcasting. Thanks again.